# How to know the home directory size limit?

Tags: permissions, files

Is there any way to know how large my home directory is allowed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i got that right you have the quota package installed on your machine?

Then it would be the command:

`repquota`
(not sure if you need to sudo it or not)

The output should look like:

```
# repquota -a 
                                Block limits               File limits 
        User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace 
        root      --  175419       0       0          14679     0     0 
        bin       --   18000       0       0            735     0     0 
        uucp      --     729       0       0             23     0     0 
        man       --      57       0       0             10     0     0 
        user1     --   13046   15360   19200            806  1500  2250 
        user2     --    2838    5120    6400            377  1000  1500
```

([Source](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Quota.html#toc5))

Answer (score 0):

Use `lsblk` command to print mounted partitions. This will give you something similar to this

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698,7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 651,9G  0 part /home
├─sda2   8:2    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0  44,8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1,8T  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

If you can't see /home partition then look at / (root, sda3 in my case) mountpoint.